# Multi index on varchar and int columns. But need to be FullText

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, indexing

Here is my query.

```
select distinct p_code from myTable 
    where ((INSTR(LOWER(subject), LOWER('jpg'))) )    
    order by code1, code2 limit  400,20;

p_code : INT
subject : VARCHAR
code1 : INT
code2 : INT
```

There is a `INSTR(subject)`, then I need to add **FullText index** to `subject` column.

And there is a `order by code1, code2`, so I think I have to add index to theses 3 columns(`subject, code1, code2`).

But as you know it's not possible to add **FullText index** because of INT columns.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: You cannot use a fulltext index to optimize ordering your result (it doesn't matter what type the columns are). You also cannot use a fulltext index for `INSTR(subject)`, just for `match () against ()`. Unless you have only a very limited number of 'jpg' in your table, your best choice here is probably an index on `(code1, code2)`, maybe extend it to `(code1, code2, p_code, subject)`. `where subject like '%jpg%'` would be a more common way to write your condition (not much faster though). Also, if your real intention is to implement pagination, there are other ways to implement it.

Comment: @Solarflare `match () against ()` was the answer! The query execution time significantly improved(6s -> 0.15s). Thanks a lot.

Comment: While I am glad it works, you should make sure you get the expected result, as the fulltext search works differently than instr or like: you will not find e.g. `myjpg`, and, unless you use `jpg*`, not `jpged` either. Also be aware of the the min word length (default:3/4). And it will get slower when the words are getting relatively more common. That is why both Rick and I didn't expect the fulltext search to be viable here, as we were making some assumption about your data like that you have a/that file extension in most of your rows. (And if that is the case, test it with a more common one).

Comment: @Solarflare Really thank your for your concern. I changed the option : `ft_min_word_len=2`, and the result is the same. Still, I haven't tested with the common words. But our language is Korean so I'm not that worried about the stopwords. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
where ((INSTR(LOWER(subject), LOWER('jpg'))) )
```

-->

```
where subject LIKE '%jpg%'
```

or probably

```
where subject LIKE '%jpg'
```

*and* use a collation on `subject` that ends in `_ci`.

But that won't speed up the query noticeably, since it *must* scan the entire table.

Even if you added `INDEX(code1, code2)`, and if the Optimizer chose to use that, it would get slower and slower as `OFFSET` increases.  But this is solvable -- by [*remembering where you left off*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) .

`FULLTEXT` is unlikely to help.

On the other hand...

If you had an `extent` column that was sometimes (or often) "jpg", then

```
where `extent` = 'jpg'
```

and

```
INDEX(extent, code1, code2)
```

would not have to do a table scan.  (Still, my link on "pagination" applies.)